# How can I add refresh button in the right click of Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, nautilus-actions

Nautilus isn't available here to get the refresh item. 
It says:

```
E: Package 'nautilus-actions' has no installation candidate
```

Is there any other way to get it?

Comment: Look for `filemanager-actions` instead.

Comment: Tried that too, but couldn't get it.